# i2c_designware seems to have problems during shutdown

Tags: power-management, shutdown

So I'll try to shutdown my Lenovo Yoga 920 with Ubuntu 18, and maybe walk away, and sometimes the computer won't actually shut down.  Sometimes I try to power it off and then put it in my backpack, and then it goes into the fun situation of NOT powering off AND overheating in the backpack until the battery runs to completely empty.

Occassionally / Usually / sometimes I'll get an error like:

```
i2c_designware i2c_designware.0: controller timed out
i2c_hid i2c-WCOM5110:00: failed to change power setting
reboot: Power down
```

Any help?  Starting to hate that I have to hard-power-off Ubuntu on a dual-boot computer.

Comment: I'm getting this as well, did you manage to resolve it?

Comment: Same here. Any updates on this on your end?

Comment: @DaveTaylor did you maybe find a solution?

Comment: I didn't work out what was causing it for certain, and it still appears occasionally but I realised that I hadn't configured secureboot correctly and once I did this problem didn't come up.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be less likely to power-off correctly if I restart, rather than power down, from windows; boot into ubuntu, and then power off or reboot as desired / required from Ubuntu - if I've restarted from Windows it seems to be able to power off from Ubuntu.

I have some suspicions about Windows setting things weirdly if it's in the middle of updating software, so I'd make sure there are no windows updates going on as well if you're having the problem.